# Code signing failed when Distribute app in Organizer

Tags: ios, xcode, signing, organizer

My xcode suddenly got a problem to Distribute any application. When I click "Distribute..." button and select a code signing identity. Here is the error message:

> **Code signing operation failed**
>
> Invalid arguments were passed to codesign.  Arguments were: --sign
>   fd2f30b26c9b384c635a044aefa90683239a434a --force
>   --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements,resource-rules /var/folders/c6/yjp3wvhx2bv34_wpcg4j779c0000gn/T/AD6840D0-4776-4EEF-BFC6-9EBA2A1188D6-212-0000012034964EA7/TestSigning.app/TestSigning

The problem happens for every project so I think it's xcode problem. The only thing I did before this problem occurs is I clicked the "Refresh" button in "Provisoning Profiles" view. All provisioning profiles are valid and I can run all the applications in my devices. The only problem is I can't distribute them.

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: this problem occurs because of InstaSign installed. I still don't find the solution

Comment: Here is the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137861/xcode-error-when-trying-to-validate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may be because you might have installed some third party signing apps (InstaSign for example). 
Download my backup of files from following URL:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xawvd81zzedz0jo/codesign.zip

Extract and paste the files at /usr/bin (Use Command+Shift+G to enter path directly.)

This should fix it.

Comment: Hopefully no one needs to explain the dangers of downloading files from some random person on the Internet...

Answer (score 1):

the distribution process is a pain in the ass. here are what I just did to solve issues, not exactly the same as yours.

1. delete all provisions in xcode
2. delete all certificate in keychains
3. "Refresh" in "Provisioning Profiles"
4. download distribution provision for the specific app
5. generate the ipa file

when generating the ipa file, I use the second option, [image: Save For Enterprise],

Other options didn't work for me

Comment: I still got the same problem even after I reinstall Xcode 4.5.2.

But I can distribute in my another Macbook air with the same provisioning profile and certificate identity.

Comment: @bagusflyer can u show the code signing identity your "another air"?

Comment: I exported my code signing identity and used in my another Macbook air. This air has no problem to distribute ipa. That means the identity is valid.So I'm totally lost.

Comment: Yes, I still got the same problem.

Comment: Must I reinstall whole system? What if I got the same problem again?

Comment: Distribution process is such a pain. and I have no good solutions for you. Steps I listed usually solve problems. but it seems it's not solve your issue. maybe it's time to call Apple Technical Support. With your developer account, you have two support ticket available.

Comment: this problem occurs because of InstaSign installed. I still don't find the solution