# Xcode Error when trying to Validate

Tags: xcode, message, code-signing, archive, submission

I have just had a App rejected, for minor reasons, I have made the requested amendments but when I try to validate before submission I get this message

Invalid arguments were passed to codesign.  Arguments were: --sign 305e91f2c1f458699df5833256815b2505f87461 --force --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements,resource-rules /var/folders/xc/6pjdg38j3_d1fc4s0_scgnsr0000gq/T/4884FF04-2DE6-47F9-8D22-0C1BEAAFE2CA-60252-00000149C7362BE9/iSuperSearch.app/iSuperSearch

I have tried looking into it but can't find an answer the only thing that is different is that I briefly tested xcode 4.6 but went back to the usual release

Thanks in advance for any help offered

Comment: Have you tried to `clean` the project, restart Xcode, restart machine?

Comment: Yeah Thanks for your reply tried That its still the same, I even went to a archive i submitted a couple of days ago tried to validate that and got the same error. I really have no clue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check which Xcode is in use by typing this on commant line:

> xcode-select --print-path

My guess is that "briefly tested xcode 4.6" might have changed the default Xcode to version 4.6, which at the moment cannot be used to submit apps to App Store. Switch back to last official Xcode release.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply I did use Xcode 4.6 for a little bit, I ended up Restoring from a cloned image I made previously. But if it happens again i'll give it a go.

Thanks Gav

Answer (score 2):

Used InstaSign or iResign perhaps? If so, fix: http://imi.im/post/2012-12-26/40046118177