# Xcode failed to sign because InstaSign was installed

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

My Xcode now fails to sign because I tried out InstaSign some time ago.

It shows "Invalid arguments were passed to codesign. Arguments were: --sign ..."

This problem also described in these two questions:

[Code signing failed when Distribute app in Organizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13813802/code-signing-failed-when-distribute-app-in-organizer#comment20481203_13813802)

[Xcode Error when trying to Validate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137861/xcode-error-when-trying-to-validate)

I know that the root cause is that InstaSign replaced /usr/bin/codesign file.

My question is where can I get the original codesign? (I know it's a little bit out of StackOverflow topic, but it's kind of related to software development).

I saw people put codesign in dropbox, but I **REALLY** dislike the idea of download binary from unknown source. So, I am looking for a some official place where I can get it.

Comment: It's a part of the Mac OS X BSD install, so you *could* just re-install the OS. (Painful, yet true.)

Comment: Should't InstaSign support be contacted in this case?

Comment: I just sent email to InstaSign.

Comment: 2middaparka: I hope I can extract it from Lion dmg file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if its related, but I installed xcode 3 on lion (unsuccessfully) and had validation errors with correct profiles. I had to download Lion distribution, then mount InstallESD.dmg from package contents/shared support and reinstall BSD.dmg

Comment: Thanks. I will download it from AppStore.

Comment: Note that this will revert a number of system binaries to older versions if they've been touched by a more recent system update.